# When I create a int pointer and instantiate an array, what is happening in memory with the array?

Tags: c++, c

Lets say I do something like this

```
int *array;
array = new int[10];
```

How is memory set up for this array?
What type is `array[0]`? (a pointer? an int?)

Comment: There are easy tests you can do to test the type of `array[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code first allocates room for a pointer called array. This memory is allocated on the stack.

Next, it allocates a block of memory from the heap to hold 10 integers and assigns the address to `array`.

`array[0]` will refer to the first integer in the block of 10. The subscript makes it a value instead of a pointer.

And for God's sakes, start accepting some answers that people are giving you!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `array[0]` has type int.

The memory is pretty simply a pointer pointing to memory to hold 10 ints that's allocated somewhere on the free store (which translates mostly to: "we honestly don't care about its address, we just care that it's our memory and we can use it 'til we delete it").

Note that in this case, you're depending on an equivalence that was originally defined in C: that `x[y]` is equivalent to `*(x+y)`. In this case, your `x` is a pointer, and addition to the pointer happens in increments of the size of the type that it points to, so when we use `array[N]`, we get the N<sup>th</sup> item in the memory pointed to by `array`.

One minor detail: you shouldn't do this -- probably ever. There's almost *never* a good reason to use `new type[size]` in C++. At one time we did because better alternatives (e.g., `std::vector`) weren't available yet -- but nowadays it's a lousy idea.

Answer (score 1):

array[0], as an element of the array, is an int.

array has already been declared a pointer to an int.

In memory, the 'new' call allocates a single block of space to hold ten integers. 'array' is a pointer to the start of that block. array[0] is the first element. array[1] is the second, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> How is memory set up for this array?

`new int[10]` will dynamically allocate enough memory from the free store to contain ten values of type `int`. It gives you a pointer to that memory, which you store in your `array` variable.

`array` itself is an automatic variable of pointer type; it's typically stored in a region of the stack that was allocated automatically for the current function call, and will be deallocated when the function returns.

Once you've finished with the memory, you must return it to the free store using `delete [] array`. Since it's easy to get that wrong, it's usually better to use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) types such as smart pointers or containers to manage dynamic resources. In this case, `std::vector<int> array(10)` will give you an array of the same size, and will automatically delete it for you when it goes out of scope.

> What type is `array[0]`?

`array[0]` is the first element of an array of `int`, so its type is `int`.